# How can I get the reports by campaign and with date

Tags: google-ads-api

I am getting the reports from the Adwords API. The formate is CampaignID, AdgroupID, Impressions, Clicks, Date.

I want to get the reports for only one campaign and the reports records should be ordered with date.

At least is there a way to get the reports for a particular campaign only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the campaign id as a predicate (a filter) to get data from just one campaign.